# Is checking for both readyState and status necessary in XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, http-status-code-200

In [this discusison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7794673/using-js-to-get-a-particular-entity?rq=1), we can see the syntax for handling *XMLHttpRequest* and guarding against a wrong *readyState* and *status* combinations as follows.

```
if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) { ... }
```

I've always been using the conjunctive conditional trusting that both cases were independent allowing for all four combinations of the operational success when contacting a server.

Yesterday, I was thinking and it hit me that I can't explain what they might be. What are they?

1. All dandy: *readyState* is done (4) and *status* is OK (200).
2. Erroneous communication: *readyState* is done (4) and *status* isn't OK (!200).
3. Not finished yet: *readyState* isn't done (!4) and *status* is OK (200).
4. ?!?!?!?!: : *readyState* isn't done (!4) and *status* is OK (!200).

In particular, I don't get how something that's not finished can be both OK and not OK (cases 3 and 4). Shouldn't it always be *status OK* when not finished yet (or always *status not OK*)?!

Comment: If you are using a modern browser, consider using the `onload` event rather than `onreadystatechange`. The `onload` event fires when the request has successfully completed, so you don't need to check `readyState`. There is also a corresponding `onerror` event.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't get how something that's not finished can be both OK and not OK (cases 3 and 4).

That isn't what you are testing for.

The test is: Is it ready? No? This condition fails.

You don't have:

```
if (request.readyState != 4 && request.status == 200) { ... }
```

or

```
if (request.readyState != 4 && request.status != 200) { ... }
```

You only care about the state when the request is finished **and** is OK.

The syntax you have is shorthand for:

```
if (request.readyState == 4) {
  if (request.status == 200) { ... }
}
```

Comment: So, if `request.status === 200` is only true when `request.readyState === 4` (*null* or *undefined* prior to that, I'm guessing), wouldn't be sufficient to only check the second if-clause? What am I missing?

Comment: `status` will have a value once the `readyState` reaches `2`, so your predicate is incorrect.

Comment: Oh, that's why. Thanks! I thought I've seen somebody explain that the *status* won't be set until *readyState* reaches the value of four. Perhaps I misunderstood. Greatly appreciate the help => +1!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest lists the status numbers and their meanings